# add page break with macro (if there isnt any page break)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to add a page break before every `heading 1` and evey `\page` bookmark.
This is my code that work :

```
Sub PageBreack(isok)
    If isok <> True Then
         Exit Sub
    End If
    Selection.GoTo What = wdGoToLine, Which = wdGoToFirst

    Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowsePage
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")
        If i > 1 Then
            ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Select
            Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous  'wdSectionBreakNextPage
        End If
        Application.Browser.Next
    Next i
    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
      If Left(p.Style, 9) = "Heading 1" Then
        p.Range.Select
        Selection.Previous.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous
      End If
    Next
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^12": .Replacement.Text = "^m": .Forward = True: .Wrap = wdFindContinue: .Format = False: .MatchCase = False: .MatchWholeWord = False: .MatchKashida = False: .MatchDiacritics = False: .MatchAlefHamza = False: .MatchControl = False: .MatchWildcards = False: .MatchSoundsLike = False: .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

My problem is that this code doesnt check that exist any page break and add a new page break there.
how to change my code that macro check if there isnt any page break add a page break ?
(English is not my native language , i hope explain clearly)

Comment: For the first requirement you don't need a macro. You can incorporate "page before" in the Heading style definition. If you don't know how to change a style definition, we need to know which version of Word is involved.

Comment: For your other requirement: Are you absolutely certain you want to force a "manual" page break at the end of every existing page, the way it's currently laying out in Word? I also note that your current code is NOT inserting page breaks. It's insert continuous section breaks. A section break is something quite different. Please double-check your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have blank pages by use page break macro
Here is a macro to delete all the blank pages in a Word Document

```
Sub Demo()
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^12[^12^13 ]{1,}"
    .Replacement.Text = "^12"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

reference:[Remove Blank Pages from Docx using word interop](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/202881b7-e053-4712-b1c8-c6cf06a60462/remove-blank-pages-from-docx-using-word-interop)

```
Sub PageBreack(isok)
    If isok <> True Then
         Exit Sub
    End If
    Selection.GoTo What = wdGoToLine, Which = wdGoToFirst

    Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowsePage
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")
        If i > 1 Then
            ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Select
            Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous  'wdSectionBreakNextPage
        End If
        Application.Browser.Next
    Next i
    With ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1").ParagraphFormat
        .PageBreakBefore = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^12": .Replacement.Text = "^m": .Forward = True: .Wrap = wdFindContinue: .Format = False: .MatchCase = False: .MatchWholeWord = False: .MatchKashida = False: .MatchDiacritics = False: .MatchAlefHamza = False: .MatchControl = False: .MatchWildcards = False: .MatchSoundsLike = False: .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "^12[^12^13 ]{1,}"
        .Replacement.Text = "^12"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If no answers come, You can use your existing code and add one more step of checking for double page breaks.

Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

```
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^m^m": .Replacement.Text = "^m": .Forward = True: .Wrap = wdFindContinue: .Format = False: .MatchCase = False: .MatchWholeWord = False: .MatchKashida = False: .MatchDiacritics = False: .MatchAlefHamza = False: .MatchControl = False: .MatchWildcards = False: .MatchSoundsLike = False: .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```